# Elasticsearch 5.2 crashes in Ubuntu14.04, EC2 t2.large machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to run ElasticSearch 5.2 hosted in an EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 machine (t2.large, which has 8gb of RAM, the minimum specified by Elastic to run Elasticsearch). But ElasticSearch is shutting down unexpectedly.
I'm not being able to understand the cause of the shutting down.

this is the elasticsearch.log:

```
[2017-03-20T10:07:53,410][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [QrRfI_U] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-03-20T10:07:53,411][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [QrRfI_U] no plugins loaded
[2017-03-20T10:07:55,555][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-03-20T10:07:55,555][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [QrRfI_U] starting ...
[2017-03-20T10:07:55,626][WARN ][i.n.u.i.MacAddressUtil   ] Failed to find a usable hardware address from the network interfaces; using random bytes: f6:fd:16:e4:90:62:fe:d6
[2017-03-20T10:07:55,673][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [QrRfI_U] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-03-20T10:07:58,755][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [QrRfI_U] new_master {QrRfI_U}{QrRfI_UKQxWwvvhvgYxGmQ}{Rne8jnb_S0KVRnXvJj1m2w}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-03-20T10:07:58,793][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [QrRfI_U] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200}
[2017-03-20T10:07:58,793][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [QrRfI_U] started
[2017-03-20T10:07:59,072][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [QrRfI_U] recovered [6] indices into cluster_state
[2017-03-20T10:07:59,724][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [QrRfI_U] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[logstash-2017.02.26][4], [logstash-2017.02.26][3], [logstash-2017.02.26][1], [logstash-2017.02.26][0]] ...]).
[2017-03-20T10:50:12,228][INFO ][o.e.c.m.MetaDataMappingService] [QrRfI_U] [logstash-2017.03.20/HXANYkA9RRKne-YAK9cNQg] update_mapping [logs]
[2017-03-20T11:06:55,449][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [QrRfI_U] stopping ...
[2017-03-20T11:06:55,514][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [QrRfI_U] stopped
[2017-03-20T11:06:55,515][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [QrRfI_U] closing ...
[2017-03-20T11:06:55,523][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [QrRfI_U] closed
```

When I restart ElasticSearch this is the node stats after 1 logstash input (I've never mmore than 3 inputs before elasticsearch crashes):
Request:
curl -i -XGET 'localhost:9200/_nodes/stats'

Response:
{"_nodes":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","nodes":{"QrRfI_UKQxWwvvhvgYxGmQ":{"timestamp":1490011241990,"name":"QrRfI_U","transport_address":"127.0.0.1:9300","host":"127.0.0.1","ip":"127.0.0.1:9300","roles":["master","data","ingest"],"indices":{"docs":{"count":17,"deleted":0},"store":{"size_in_bytes":235863,"throttle_time_in_millis":0},"indexing":{"index_total":2,"index_time_in_millis":111,"index_current":0,"index_failed":0,"delete_total":0,"delete_time_in_millis":0,"delete_current":0,"noop_update_total":0,"is_throttled":false,"throttle_time_in_millis":0},"get":{"total":2,"time_in_millis":3,"exists_total":2,"exists_time_in_millis":3,"missing_total":0,"missing_time_in_millis":0,"current":0},"search":{"open_contexts":0,"query_total":84,"query_time_in_millis":70,"query_current":0,"fetch_total":80,"fetch_time_in_millis":91,"fetch_current":0,"scroll_total":0,"scroll_time_in_millis":0,"scroll_current":0,"suggest_total":0,"suggest_time_in_millis":0,"suggest_current":0},"merges":{"current":0,"current_docs":0,"current_size_in_bytes":0,"total":0,"total_time_in_millis":0,"total_docs":0,"total_size_in_bytes":0,"total_stopped_time_in_millis":0,"total_throttled_time_in_millis":0,"total_auto_throttle_in_bytes":545259520},"refresh":{"total":2,"total_time_in_millis":89,"listeners":0},"flush":{"total":0,"total_time_in_millis":0},"warmer":{"current":0,"total":28,"total_time_in_millis":72},"query_cache":{"memory_size_in_bytes":0,"total_count":0,"hit_count":0,"miss_count":0,"cache_size":0,"cache_count":0,"evictions":0},"fielddata":{"memory_size_in_bytes":0,"evictions":0},"completion":{"size_in_bytes":0},"segments":{"count":17,"memory_in_bytes":137618,"terms_memory_in_bytes":130351,"stored_fields_memory_in_bytes":5304,"term_vectors_memory_in_bytes":0,"norms_memory_in_bytes":384,"points_memory_in_bytes":15,"doc_values_memory_in_bytes":1564,"index_writer_memory_in_bytes":0,"version_map_memory_in_bytes":0,"fixed_bit_set_memory_in_bytes":0,"max_unsafe_auto_id_timestamp":-1,"file_sizes":{}},"translog":{"operations":2,"size_in_bytes":6072},"request_cache":{"memory_size_in_bytes":12740,"evictions":0,"hit_count":0,"miss_count":20},"recovery":{"current_as_source":0,"current_as_target":0,"throttle_time_in_millis":0}},"os":{"timestamp":1490011241998,"cpu":{"percent":1,"load_average":{"1m":0.18,"5m":0.08,"15m":0.06}},"mem":{"total_in_bytes":8371847168,"free_in_bytes":5678006272,"used_in_bytes":2693840896,"free_percent":68,"used_percent":32},"swap":{"total_in_bytes":0,"free_in_bytes":0,"used_in_bytes":0}},"process":{"timestamp":1490011241998,"open_file_descriptors":220,"max_file_descriptors":66000,"cpu":{"percent":1,"total_in_millis":14800},"mem":{"total_virtual_in_bytes":3171389440}},"jvm":{"timestamp":1490011241998,"uptime_in_millis":205643,"mem":{"heap_used_in_bytes":195922864,"heap_used_percent":37,"heap_committed_in_bytes":519438336,"heap_max_in_bytes":519438336,"non_heap_used_in_bytes":75810224,"non_heap_committed_in_bytes":81326080,"pools":{"young":{"used_in_bytes":96089960,"max_in_bytes":139591680,"peak_used_in_bytes":139591680,"peak_max_in_bytes":139591680},"survivor":{"used_in_bytes":11413088,"max_in_bytes":17432576,"peak_used_in_bytes":17432576,"peak_max_in_bytes":17432576},"old":{"used_in_bytes":88419816,"max_in_bytes":362414080,"peak_used_in_bytes":88419816,"peak_max_in_bytes":362414080}}},"threads":{"count":43,"peak_count":45},"gc":{"collectors":{"young":{"collection_count":5,"collection_time_in_millis":164},"old":{"collection_count":1,"collection_time_in_millis":39}}},"buffer_pools":{"direct":{"count":29,"used_in_bytes":70307265,"total_capacity_in_bytes":70307264},"mapped":{"count":17,"used_in_bytes":217927,"total_capacity_in_bytes":217927}},"classes":{"current_loaded_count":10981,"total_loaded_count":10981,"total_unloaded_count":0}},"thread_pool":{"bulk":{"threads":2,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":2,"completed":2},"fetch_shard_started":{"threads":4,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":4,"completed":26},"fetch_shard_store":{"threads":0,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":0,"completed":0},"flush":{"threads":0,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":0,"completed":0},"force_merge":{"threads":0,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":0,"completed":0},"generic":{"threads":4,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":4,"completed":54},"get":{"threads":2,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":2,"completed":2},"index":{"threads":0,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":0,"completed":0},"listener":{"threads":0,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":0,"completed":0},"management":{"threads":5,"queue":0,"active":1,"rejected":0,"largest":5,"completed":203},"refresh":{"threads":1,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":1,"completed":550},"search":{"threads":4,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":4,"completed":165},"snapshot":{"threads":0,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":0,"completed":0},"warmer":{"threads":1,"queue":0,"active":0,"rejected":0,"largest":1,"completed":23}},"fs":{"timestamp":1490011241999,"total":{"total_in_bytes":8309932032,"free_in_bytes":3226181632,"available_in_bytes":2780459008},"data":[{"path":"/home/ubuntu/elasticsearch-5.2.0/data/nodes/0","mount":"/ (/dev/xvda1)","type":"ext4","total_in_bytes":8309932032,"free_in_bytes":3226181632,"available_in_bytes":2780459008,"spins":"false"}],"io_stats":{"devices":[{"device_name":"xvda1","operations":901,"read_operations":4,"write_operations":897,"read_kilobytes":16,"write_kilobytes":10840}],"total":{"operations":901,"read_operations":4,"write_operations":897,"read_kilobytes":16,"write_kilobytes":10840}}},"transport":{"server_open":0,"rx_count":10,"rx_size_in_bytes":3388,"tx_count":10,"tx_size_in_bytes":3388},"http":{"current_open":5,"total_opened":12},"breakers":{"request":{"limit_size_in_bytes":311663001,"limit_size":"297.2mb","estimated_size_in_bytes":0,"estimated_size":"0b","overhead":1.0,"tripped":0},"fielddata":{"limit_size_in_bytes":311663001,"limit_size":"297.2mb","estimated_size_in_bytes":0,"estimated_size":"0b","overhead":1.03,"tripped":0},"in_flight_requests":{"limit_size_in_bytes":519438336,"limit_size":"495.3mb","estimated_size_in_bytes":0,"estimated_size":"0b","overhead":1.0,"tripped":0},"parent":{"limit_size_in_bytes":363606835,"limit_size":"346.7mb","estimated_size_in_bytes":0,"estimated_size":"0b","overhead":1.0,"tripped":0}},"script":{"compilations":0,"cache_evictions":0},"discovery":{"cluster_state_queue":{"total":0,"pending":0,"committed":0}},"ingest":{"total":{"count":0,"time_in_millis":0,"current":0,"failed":0},"pipelines":{}}}}}